# PHP gettext and conditional statements

Tags: php, translation, gettext, poedit, php-gettext

Translating a website with gettext and PoEdit for the first time, I noticed that the messages generated by conditional statements are ignored.

How can PoEdit get the messages from a switch construct like this, for example?

```
if ($a == 1)
    echo _("Text one");
else if ($a == 2)
    echo _("Text two");
else if ($a == 3)
    echo _("More text .. $b");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a "switch statement", but regardless, I assure you that neither Poedit nor xgettext (which is what does the extraction) treats code inside `if` statements any differently from any other code.

Whatever the problem is with your unknown code and your unknown Poedit configuration / xgettext invocation is impossible to say. What *is* possible to say, with certainly, is that it is not related to conditional statements — that would be utterly ridiculous and non-functional (can you imagine non-trivial piece of code *without* any branching?).